# How to add text to the start of all comments?

Tags: php, comments

For example somebody replies-

Hi! This is a Comment!

but is published as

Text- Hi! This is a Comment!

Any ideas folks?  I'm totally stumped.  I want to add the extra text so it appears within the comment rather than before/around it in the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [`comment_text`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L852) filter:

```
/**
 * Prepend text to each comment content.
 */

add_filter( 'comment_text', function( $comment_text )
{
    $text = 'Some text';
    return $text . $comment_text;
});
```

if you're displaying the comment text with:

```
<?php comment_text(); ?>
```

Comment: That adds text above the comment, is there a simple fix to having it show on the same line as the comment?  If there is or if there isnt, thank you loads for replying to a total newb.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I'm not sure I follow you there, what you mean by the same line. You can also try out the `get_comment_text` filter, that's activated before the `comment_text` filter.

Comment: The comments are displaying Some Text and the Comment with what look like paragraph breaks between them.

Comment: Maybe you could add the current HTML structure of a comment, before and after the filter. So we can better understand how it's working.

Comment: I can't at the moment as I'm being murdered in work but shall post the code later on.  Thanks for looking in, its appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addText() { 
        var input = document.getElementById('comment');
        input.value = 'lots of new text ' + input.value;
    }
</script>

<p class="comment-form-comment">
<label for="comment">Comment</label>
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-describedby="form-allowed-tags" aria-required="true">
</textarea>
</p>
```

Ripped bits and pieces from elsewhere online.. eventually.  Thanks for the help.